# My dLookup function keeps giving errors

Tags: ms-access

This may seem like I might be asking the same question as the ones people have asked before but even after going through all those answers I cant find what is wrong with my DLookUp expression.

```
=DLookUp("F5","[Store Sheet]","[Item ID=]" & [ItemNameBox])
```

Basically, what this is supposed to do is  using the value in the ItemNameBox (which creates a list of Items from the store sheet, in a dropdown). What I want to do is that when the name of an item is selected the corresponding value store in F5 should be displayed in the text box.
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct syntax:

```
=DLookUp("F5","[Store Sheet]","[Item ID] = " & [ItemNameBox] & "")
```

If Item ID is text, then:

```
=DLookUp("F5","[Store Sheet]","[Item ID] = '" & [ItemNameBox] & "'")
```

Comment: Note that if [Item ID] is numeric then you don't need the trailing `& ""` in the first example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried both of those but they don't seem to work, I'm still getting an error 
http://i.imgur.com/7neqdXz.png is the Storeroom Sheet that has the values

Comment: I changed the name of "F5" to "Stock Unit" for better understanding 
and this http://i.imgur.com/y6bfTws.png is form where im trying to use Dlookup

Comment: Your "Item Name" combobox must be bound to "Item ID" (or "Item No").

Comment: Isn't it already due to the link I made, using lookup wizard?